# Access table, cannot export hidden query

Tags: ms-access, export-to-xml

I use MS Access 2007. I have created simple select query and later I used hidden attribute.

My question is why I cannot export data to XML while having hidden attribute?

Comment: you mean parameter? you need to pass the parameter somehow before executing/exporting the query.

Comment: @krishKM, no... I have a hidden query - attribute. When it is hidden it is impossible to export data.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to unhide it before the export, then hide it again:

```
QueryName = "NameOfYourQuery"
SetHiddenAttribute acQuery, QueryName, False
' Run your export.
SetHiddenAttribute acQuery, QueryName, True
```

Comment: Okay but why is this happenning? Is hidden table different from the unhidden one? Is there some sort rule for that?

Comment: I guess so. If you could just export a hidden query, it may not make much sense to hide it. Instead of hiding it, you could rename it with a leading `USys` - that will also hide it from a normal view.

Comment: Hm... a little offtop but is there a way to hide query from other users and yet be able to use it normally?

Comment: There was with _user level security_ which lived from Access 1.0 to 2003, then it was dropped. Or to be precise: It exists with the `mdb` file format, not with the `accdb` format.